Trying to determine if my CPU support ECC
I try to determine if my PC supports ECC or not.
The parts I use: Asrock QC5000M motherboard with a soldered AMD A4-5000 CPU and 2x2GB ECC udimm ram.
Dmidecode says:
# dmidecode 3.4
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 2.8 present.

Handle 0x0010, DMI type 16, 23 bytes
Physical Memory Array
    Location: System Board Or Motherboard
    Use: System Memory
    Error Correction Type: None
    Maximum Capacity: 4 GB
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Number Of Devices: 2

Handle 0x0012, DMI type 17, 40 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0010
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 72 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 2 GB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: DIMM 0
    Bank Locator: CHANNEL A
    Type: DDR3
    Type Detail: Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered)
    Speed: 667 MT/s
    Manufacturer: <BAD INDEX>
    Serial Number: 18323E99
    Asset Tag: Hynix/Hyundai  
    Part Number: HMT325U7BFR8A-H9  
    Rank: 1
    Configured Memory Speed: 667 MT/s
    Minimum Voltage: 1.35 V
    Maximum Voltage: 1.5 V
    Configured Voltage: 1.5 V

Handle 0x0013, DMI type 17, 40 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0010
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 72 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 2 GB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: DIMM 1
    Bank Locator: CHANNEL A
    Type: DDR3
    Type Detail: Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered)
    Speed: 667 MT/s
    Manufacturer: <BAD INDEX>
    Serial Number: 18C23E9E
    Asset Tag: Hynix/Hyundai  
    Part Number: HMT325U7BFR8A-H9  
    Rank: 1
    Configured Memory Speed: 667 MT/s
    Minimum Voltage: 1.35 V
    Maximum Voltage: 1.5 V
    Configured Voltage: 1.5 V

Edac-ctl says: edac-ctl: drivers not loaded.
Edac-util says: edac-util: EDAC drivers loaded. No memory controllers found.
If I try to load the amd64_edac module, modprobe comlains: modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'amd64_edac': No such device.
I tried to debug based on the sourcecode and this article if my cpu should support ECC.
Lspci -s 0:18 -n returns the following:
00:18.0 0600: 1022:1530
00:18.1 0600: 1022:1531
00:18.2 0600: 1022:1532
00:18.3 0600: 1022:1533
00:18.4 0600: 1022:1534
00:18.5 0600: 1022:1535

The source seems to expect the following IDs (this is a family 16h, model 0 cpu):
#define PCI_DEVICE_ID_AMD_16H_NB_F1 0x1531
#define PCI_DEVICE_ID_AMD_16H_NB_F2 0x1532

I am verrry novice in C and also in linux so I failed to understand why the module fails to load. Could someone please help me understand this topic?
My OS is a Debian 12 with the kernel: 6.1.0-21-amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Debian 6.1.90-1 (2024-05-03) x86_64 GNU/Linux.

A quick Internet Search suggests that your CPU doesn't support ECC

Yes, I am aware that this cpu officially does not support ECC, but there were server processors based on the same microarchitecture, like the opteron x2150 and that did supprt ECC officially. What I would like to know is exactly what amd64_edac looks for and does not find.

@ComputerNoob456: ECC requires physical pins on the chip. The microarchitecture may support ECC, but that doesn't mean that the CPU die is wired up to support ECC.

I try to determine if my PC supports ECC or not
No, it does not:

Memory

2 x DDR3 DIMM Slots
Supports DDR3 1600/1333/1066 non-ECC, un-buffered memory
Max. capacity of system memory: 32GB*


Source: ASRock > QC5000M
